# Get values from an array of objects and check it on fly &

Tags: javascript

```
const items = [{ price: 250 }, { price: -150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 500 }];
let result = items.map(({ price }) => price);
console.log(result);
```

Is it possible to somehow embed a check in this place - items.map((**{ price }**) => price); - to check for a negative value, or do I need to do it again, map ?

UPD: I want to get summ of all numbers, except negative

Comment: Yes, you can check if it's negative... `price < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive'`

Comment: What outcome do you actually want?

Comment: you want to get only negative numbers? then `.filter()` is a good option

Comment: I get summ of all numbers, except negative

Comment: See "[How to skip over an element in .map()?](/q/24806772/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `.filter()` method to get only the objects with negative values

```js
const items = [{ price: 250 }, { price: -150 }, { price: 150 }, { price: 500 }];

const result = items.filter(val => {
  return val.price < 0;
});

console.log(result)
```

or It can be done like this in one line

```
const result = items.filter(val => val.price < 0);
```